# Get coordinate values of defect's object

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, convex-hull

I found contours and hull using OpenCV methods(C++) on image. And I want to draw defects points. I found defects points by calling

```
vector<Vec4i> defects;
convexityDefects(contours, hull, defects);
```

There are 4 integer number each defect. Which one is x coordinate?  I want to get defects points's coordinates. I will draw starter points of black lines which are on hand.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like: `Point p = contours[defects[d][2]]`

---

I'll quote just the meaningful part of the documentation:

> [...] 4-element integer vector: (start_index, end_index, farthest_pt_index, fixpt_depth), where indices are **0-based indices in the original contour** of the convexity defect [...]

So the returned values represent indexes in the original contour.

`defects[d]` represents the `d`-th contour. Then you take its 3rd member, `farthest_pt_index`, which is at `defects[d][2]`. This integer is the index of a point in the original contour that is the farthest from the hull, i.e. the lower arrow head on the drawing. Its coordinates:

```
Point p = contours[defects[d][2]]
int x = p.x
int y = p.y
```

And if you want to know how far this point is from the hull, you'll have to divide the 4-th element by 256: `float p_distance = defects[d][3] / 256.0`

Answer (score 0):

[The doc on convexityDefects()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexitydefects):

> **convexityDefects** – The output vector of convexity defects. In C++ and the new Python/Java interface each convexity defect is represented as 4-element integer vector (a.k.a. `cv::Vec4i`): (`start_index`, `end_index`, `farthest_pt_index`, `fixpt_depth`), where indices are 0-based indices in the original contour of the convexity defect beginning, end and the farthest point, and `fixpt_depth` is fixed-point approximation (with 8 fractional bits) of the distance between the farthest contour point and the hull. That is, to get the floating-point value of the depth will be `fixpt_depth/256.0`.

So each convexity defect consists of several points, from `start_index` to `end_index` in the `countour` parameter of `convexityDefects()`.

Comment: I read already it. But I don't understand. A contour contains points, and it have x-y coordinates. But the defect has only 4 integers. When I want to draw it, what do I use?

Comment: Each convexity defect consists of several points, from `start_index` to `end_index` in the `contour` you passed to the `convexityDefects()` function.

Comment: As I understand, the start and end points are on convex hull, so you should drop a perpendicular from farthest to [start, end].